# Angular Material: Usage of errorStateMatcher with ngFor

Tags: forms, validation, angular-material, angular6

I'm using Angular 6.0.9 and Angular Material 6.5.4. In my form I have an ngFor loop for the inputs with an errorStateMatcher to validate the input.

The problem is that if the content of an input field is invalid, all other fields will also be marked as invalid (even if they are not dirty). I want to make sure that only the current field that is actually invalid is marked as red.

See a self-explanatory example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1jyhw?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs all share the same form control `emailFormControl`. You need a separate form control for each input. It is okay to use the same `ErrorStateMatcher` but not `FormControl`